# Can iOS users with older devices see and download a previous version of my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, 64-bit, app-store-connect

My app is currently available in the App Store for both `armv7` and `arm64` architectures. Let's say it is the version **1.0**.
Due to the large size of the binary I'm considering the idea of targeting only 64-bit devices to avoid the armv7 and armv7s slices in the fat binary. Bitcode is currently not an option due to 3rd party frameworks (specially Google) so 64-bit targeting is my last resort. Let's say it will be the version **2.0**.

What happens when an user if a `armv7` device looks up my app on the App Store?
AFAIK, If the user has previously downloaded the app version **1.0**, it will be given an option to download **1.0** again (i.e.: restore the previous download).

However, what if the user has never downloaded the app before? Will it be given the option to download **1.0** as the 'last compatibly' version of the app? Or will it be forced to download **2.0**, which does not run in the user's device?

I'd like to submit an `arm64` update without restricting my audience (there's no problem if `armv7` users still use a previous version of the app).

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Nicolas Braun, since my app currently supports both `armv7` and `arm64` I'm not able to submit an `arm64`-only update since it would restrict device requirements.

What if I submit an update that **requires** `iOS >= 9` without bitcode support, would customers be able to download the variant that contains only the executable architecture needed for the target device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First once you made an application available to a set of devices your are not allowed to add technical restrictions (ie device capabilities) that will prevent it from running on devices that were previously compatible.

It is stated in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1) even though really not clear:

> Important: All device requirement changes must be made when you submit an update to your binary. You are permitted only to expand your device requirements. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted. You are unable to restrict device requirements because this action will keep customers who have previously downloaded your app from running new updates.

The only parameter you can change that restrict the compatible devices is the minimum OS version. More specificaly

> Developers can add restrictions to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities on app updates provided any device that is dropped cannot support the min os version specified.
>   [Source](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/)

That said I believe App Thinning will work on iOS9 no matter if Bitcode is activated or not. Taken from [Apple App Thinning doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the executable **architecture** and resources that are needed for the target device.

You can see in the same link that bitcode is not the same thing.

Cheers,

Nicolas

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so, you mean 1) I'm not allowed to submit an `arm64` only version since I current support `armv7` 2) If I submit a binary that requires `iOS >= 9` without bitcode support App Thinning you still work, in other words, users will be able to download smaller binaries (containing only the executable architecture for the user's device)?